# Can't call the function with onclick in html/php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

HTML/PHP:

```
<?php foreach($lines as $line): ?>
<form method="GET" action="nextpage">
   <?php 
       global $unitPRICE;
       $unitPRICE=(float) $line[1];
       global $quantity;
       $quantity=(float) $line[2];
   ?>
   <tr>
      <td> <div name="NomP"> <?php echo "<p>".$line[0]."</p>"; ?> </div> 
          <input class="btn" name="delbtn" type="button" onclick="deleteproduct(this.form)" value="Delete"> 
      </td>
      <td> 
          <div id="fixedP">
              <input type="text" name="FIXEDP" value="<?php echo $unitPRICE; ?>" readonly> 
          </div>
      </td>
      <td> <input type="number" id="quantity" class="qty" oninput="modPrice(this.form)" value="<?php echo $quantity;?>" ></td>
      <td > 
          <div> 
              <input id="price"type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $unitPRICE*$quantity; ?>" readonly>
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Javascript:

```
function deleteproduct(frm){
    var deletebtn= frm.elements['delbtn'];
    console.log(typeof deletebtn);
}
```

The Error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteproduct is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (cart.php:55)

Also, the main goal of this function is to print the text the div with the id "Nomp".

Comment: Assign an `id` to your form and let `deleteproduct()` find the form by the given id --> `deleteproduct(form_id)`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one line on the HTML. There are multiple forms like this printed which makes the id a little bit useless (maybe...idk).

Comment: _..which makes the id a little bit useless..._ Absolutly the opposite is true

Comment: Can you explain pls I'm lost

Comment: How is the js code implemented - in script tag in the head or at the end of the body or in an external script? Furthermore i'm not sure if ```this.form``` is working...

Comment: It is at the head of the page is the link to an external script.

Comment: @Bob, you can check, but the file where the function is located, is not being imported correctly.

Comment: I did check the file and it is being. I added other functions to it and they work. Also, if I want to implement the javascript in the HTML page, where should I implement the function (head or at the end of the page)?